# Pandas element wise if/else (IIF)

Tags: pandas

Is there a element-wise IIF function in Pandas?

E.g. given a dataframe:

```
w = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.to_datetime(['2016-01-01','2016-01-02','2016-01-03']),'A1':[0.3,0.1,0.1],'A2':[0.4,0.4,0.4]}).set_index(['Date'])
```

If the element > 0.2, set to 1, else set to 0. Such as below:

```
w2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.to_datetime(['2016-01-01','2016-01-02','2016-01-03']),'A1':[1,0,0],'A2':[1,1,1]}).set_index(['Date'])
```

There is mask()/where(), but the true value is from the old dataframe.

Comment: maybe you can add expected output from your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need compare with `0.2` and `boolean DataFrame` cast to `np.uint8`:

```
print (w > .2)
               A1    A2
Date                   
2016-01-01   True  True
2016-01-02  False  True
2016-01-03  False  True

w1 = (w > .2).astype(np.uint8)
print (w1)
            A1  A2
Date              
2016-01-01   1   1
2016-01-02   0   1
2016-01-03   0   1
```

---

```
print (w.gt(.2).astype(np.uint8))
            A1  A2
Date              
2016-01-01   1   1
2016-01-02   0   1
2016-01-03   0   1
```

Comparing solutions:

```
#[300000 rows x 2 columns]
#for testing index is not necessary
w = pd.concat([w]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [49]: %timeit ((w > .2).astype(int))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.11 ms per loop

In [50]: %timeit ((w > .2).astype(np.short))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.8 ms per loop

In [51]: %timeit ((w > .2).astype(np.uint8))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.35 ms per loop

In [82]: %timeit (w.gt(.2).astype(np.uint8))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.02 ms per loop

In [52]: %timeit (w.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x>0.2 else 0))
1 loop, best of 3: 334 ms per loop
```

Thank you [`piRSquared`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627300/pandas-element-wise-if-else-iif/41628329?noredirect=1#comment70462298_41628329) for another solution:

```
pd.DataFrame((w.values > .2).astype(np.uint8), w.index, w.columns)


In [112]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame((w.values > .2).astype(np.uint8), w.index, w.columns))
1000 loops, best of 3: 877 µs per loop
```

Comment: @piRSquared - Thank you.

Comment: @piRSquared - I am going check your solutions too ;)

Comment: no, just add this one to your list `pd.DataFrame((w.values > .2).astype(np.uint8), w.index, w.columns)`

Answer (score 2):

The answer by [jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41628329/4804108) is what I would use for this.
Alternatively you could also use [DataFrame.applymap](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) function.

```
w.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x>0.2 else 0)
```